# Find the top 5 nearest locations from given location

Tags: android, list, google-maps, sorting, location-based-service

I am creating an app in which I need top 5 nearest riders location from cook location and then store in list an ascending order. I have found the nearest rider location from cook location. But i am bit confused how to add top 5 in list.

That's my code for finding nearest rider location.

```
try {
            for(Location rlocation : rLocations){
                float distance=  cookerLOCATION.distanceTo(rlocation);
                //int distance = Location.distanceBetween(cookLAT,cookLONG,rlocation.getLatitude(),rlocation.getLongitude(),results);
                if(smallestDistance == -1 || distance < smallestDistance){
                    colsestRiderLocation = rlocation;
                    smallestDistance = distance;
                    comparingValues();
                    Log.d("Closet Rider Location",colsestRiderLocation.toString());
                }
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have to replace "smallestDistance" by an array of 5 and then just test every cases and you will have the closest one in the first element of the array and the far one ine the fifth element of the array :

```
if(smallestDistance[0] == -1 || distance < smallestDistance[0]){
    colsestRiderLocation = rlocation;
    smallestDistance[0] = distance;
    comparingValues();
    Log.d("Closet Rider Location",colsestRiderLocation.toString());
            }
else if(smallestDistance[1] == -1 || distance < smallestDistance[1]){
    colsestRiderLocation = rlocation;
    smallestDistance[1] = distance;
    Log.d("Second closet Rider Location",colsestRiderLocation.toString());
}
else if(smallestDistance[2] == -1 || distance < smallestDistance[2]){
    colsestRiderLocation = rlocation;
    smallestDistance[2] = distance;
    Log.d("Third closet Rider Location",colsestRiderLocation.toString());
}
else if(smallestDistance[3] == -1 || distance < smallestDistance[3]){
    colsestRiderLocation = rlocation;
    smallestDistance[3] = distance;
    Log.d("Fourth closet Rider Location",colsestRiderLocation.toString());
}
else if(smallestDistance[4] == -1 || distance < smallestDistance[4]){
    colsestRiderLocation = rlocation;
    smallestDistance[4] = distance;
    Log.d("Fifth closet Rider Location",colsestRiderLocation.toString());
}
```

Comment: I think this will store the same location. Like top 1st nearest rider.

Comment: I don't think, bacause the nearest will never enter in the "else" statement. It will enter one time in the first if and won't be called another time so it won't enter on the other "else"

Comment: Can I use ArrayList rather than array?. Because i have to create dynamic structure.

Comment: Yes I think this should work the same way, I haven't tried

Comment: I found a problem when assigning value -1 to array. it set value on index 0. it give me exception ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. I think error would be same for ArrayList. @Aznhar

Comment: ArrayList are empty by definition, did you add element ? You can't set value without adding element first

Comment: I am currently working on arrays. I created array like: public  static Double[] smallestDistance =new Double[]{Double.valueOf(-1)};

Comment: Well in this case, it worked for me : smallestDistance[0] = -1d;

Comment: double, don't forget toadd "d" letter after "-1" so your compiler will understand that -1 is a double

Comment: By using this smallestDistance[0] = -1d you are adding value to index 0. But when i am comparing with index 1 or 2 and so on it the same error.

Comment: That's because your array has only one element when you initialized it. You need to make it bigger at the beginning like : Double[] smallestDistance =new Double[]{-1d,-1d,-1d,-1d,-1d}; for 5 value

Comment: What should i do?

Comment: For static size of Array : Double[] smallestDistance =new Double[]{-1d,-1d,-1d,-1d,-1d}; And for dynamic : ArrayList<Double> smallestDistance = new ArrayList<Double>();
smallestDistance.add(-1d);
smallestDistance.add(-1d);
smallestDistance.add(-1d);
smallestDistance.add(-1d);
smallestDistance.add(-1d);

Comment: Currently i run it for top 2 riders. It gave me same value like for 1st and 2nd.